# Select rows that meet a condition and occur for 10 consecutive seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have some time series data below:

```
    Truck                       Timestamp           b2_v_fult2_tms_err  tm2_b_fault_level_a tm2_b_fault_code_a
0   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:48 NaN                 2.0                 30.0                    
1   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:51 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
2   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:52 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
3   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:53 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
4   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:54 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
5   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:55 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
6   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:56 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
7   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:57 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
8   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:58 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
9   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:59 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
10  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:12:00 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
11  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:05 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
12  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:10 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
13  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:11 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
14  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:15 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
15  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:16 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
16  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:20 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
17  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:21 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
18  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:26 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
19  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:27 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 
20  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:31 0.0                 0.0                 0.0
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is finding rows where "b2_v_fult2_tms_err == 1.0", "tm2_b_fault_level_a == 0.0", "tm2_b_fault_code_a == 0.0", creating a new column named "bin", and inserting a "True" value in the "bin" column next to the rows where the three values ("b2_v_fult2_tms_err == 1.0", "tm2_b_fault_level_a == 0.0", "tm2_b_fault_code_a == 0.0") occur for 10 consecutive seconds. All other rows in the "bin" column can be left blank or marked "False".

What this would look like is:

```
    Truck                       Timestamp           b2_v_fult2_tms_err  tm2_b_fault_level_a tm2_b_fault_code_a  bin
0   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:48 NaN                 2.0                 30.0                False
1   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:51 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
2   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:52 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
3   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:53 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
4   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:54 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
5   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:55 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
6   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:56 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
7   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:57 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
8   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:58 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
9   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:11:59 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
10  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 13:12:00 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 True
11  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:05 1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
12  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:10 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
13  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:11 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
14  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:15 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
15  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:16 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
16  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:20 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
17  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:21 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
18  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:26 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
19  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:27 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
20  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828   2023-05-01 14:58:31 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 False
```

I have filtered the data using `bin1_df = results_df.loc[(results_df['b2_v_fult2_tms_err'] == 1.0) & (results_df['tm2_b_fault_level_a'] == 0.0) & (results_df['tm2_b_fault_code_a'] == 0.0) ].reset_index(drop=True)` and then tried using `bin1_df['time_diff'] = bin1_df['Timestamp'].diff()` to calculate the difference between timestamps, which was successful. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to turn 10 occurrences of 1's into "True" values. After that I used `m = bin1_df['time_diff'] == pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)` to filter the results to display rows where the timedelta is one second and then using `bin1_df = bin1_df[m.shift(-1)|m]` to display the row before as it would leave out the first row.

I've also tried a few other things that led nowhere but the above attempt was the closest I could get.

Would anyone know how to accomplish this? It doesn't have to be exactly this result, but something that can clearly communicate that these conditions were met for 10 seconds is all I'm ultimately looking for.

Comment: can you make your examples minimal? Remove the columns that are not needed and clean the format, data is not readable currently

Comment: @SurajShourie I have cleaned the format to make it more readable, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
m1 = df["b2_v_fult2_tms_err"] == 1.0
m2 = df["tm2_b_fault_level_a"] == 0.0
m3 = df["tm2_b_fault_code_a"] == 0.0

m = m1 & m2 & m3

df["bin"] = df.groupby((m != m.shift()).cumsum())["Timestamp"].transform(
    lambda g: ([True] * 10 + [False] * (len(g) - 10))
    if len(g) >= 10
    else [False] * len(g)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        Truck            Timestamp  b2_v_fult2_tms_err  tm2_b_fault_level_a  tm2_b_fault_code_a    bin
0   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:48                 NaN                  2.0                30.0  False
1   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:51                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
2   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:52                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
3   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:53                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
4   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:54                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
5   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:55                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
6   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:56                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
7   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:57                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
8   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:58                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
9   251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:11:59                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
10  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 13:12:00                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0   True
11  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:05                 1.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
12  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:10                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
13  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:11                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
14  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:15                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
15  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:16                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
16  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:20                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
17  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:21                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
18  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:26                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
19  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:27                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
20  251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828  2023-05-01 14:58:31                 0.0                  0.0                 0.0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty here is to find n consecutive occurrences of 1 sec difference.

First get difference on a seconds level:

```
# create a mask based on your filter
df['mask'] = (df['b2_v_fult2_tms_err'] == 1) & (df['tm2_b_fault_code_a']  == 0) & (df['tm2_b_fault_level_a'] ==0)

# get sec difference in the Timestamp column
df['time_diff'] = df['Timestamp'].diff().dt.seconds
```

Next identify the timesteps that are consecutive and under a threshold

```
threshold = 9 # set your threshold for consecutive secs here
# this will identify consecutive occurences of same value (1 second in this example)
df['bin'] = df.time_diff.groupby((df.time_diff != df.time_diff.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size') * df.time_diff
df['bin'] = (df.bin >= threshold).astype(int)
df['bin'] = df['bin'] * df['mask'] # consecutive time and satisfy filter

# i've added helper columns for readability but they are not a necessity
cols_to_keep = ['Truck', 'Timestamp', 'b2_v_fult2_tms_err', 'tm2_b_fault_level_a', 'tm2_b_fault_code_a', 'bin']

df[cols_to_keep]
```

OUTPUT:

| Truck | Timestamp | b2_v_fult2_tms_err | tm2_b_fault_level_a | tm2_b_fault_code_a | bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:48 | nan | 2 | 30 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:51 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:52 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:53 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:54 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:55 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:56 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:57 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:58 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:11:59 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 13:12:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:05 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:16 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:26 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:27 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 251_EV01_PB_579_HD_756828 | 2023-05-01 14:58:31 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |